# What are possible approaches to deal with unseparable data even after PCA?

Tags: classification, dataset, feature-selection, prediction, pca

Greetings data scientists,

I am dealing with a complex classification/prediction problem and I am finding very difficult to separate the classes at all.
Even after PCA, my data (over the two PCs), look like this:

[image: PC1 and PC2 plot]

Given this dataset, what approach could be best to accurately predict the classes?

Background: I am trying to classifying modelled problems via the best approach/algorithm to solve them.

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you please indicate what is X-axis and Y-axis?
Are there the only features you got after the projection?

Comment: PCA applies linear projections, so applying it can make classes *less* separable if there are complex non-linear effects in play. I am not saying that is the case here, it is not possible to tell from your question, and entirely possible your data does not predict the label. How many training examples do you have? Resolving non-linear relationships will take a non-linear model (e.g. neural nets or something like xgboost), and usually a large number of training examples, because there are so many more possible ways a non-linear relationship could be expressed than a linear one.

Comment: As Neil noted in the comments, there might be non-linear relationships present in the data. If you still need to perform PCA, then it might be worth looking at [Kernel PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_principal_component_analysis). [PS: Sorry, couldn't post this as a comment]

Answer (score 2):

Is your problem unsupervised? If not, the data does not need to be "visually" separable in two dimensions, you can use classifiers in multiple dimensions to create separations for you (linear or nonlinear, just depends on the classifier).

If your problem is unsupervised try other methods for clustering data such a K-Means or tree-based clustering (i.e. hierarchical).

Comment: One other unsupervised, and usually very strong, clustering algorithm is t-SNE.

Answer (score 1):

It is not important that the data is separable in 2-D. You can try a PCA + SVM combination to check at which point (number of dimensions) the data is best separated. You can do it with Grid Search on the parameters of PCA.

If you are just visualising the data, you can try T-SNE embedding as well.